# Ensuring sequential incrementation or primary key using JPA annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have some simple properties tables that all extend a @MappedSuperclass.

Each property table needs to have their own unique long sequence starting from 1L. So, the number of records in the table will always equal the primary key value of the last insert.

I want to use the @GeneratedValue annotation however I a not sure which strategy to use that will ensure that each table has its own sequence of primary keys from 1L upwards.

Any advice would be appreciated.

I am using Hibernate as my JPA implementation.

***THERE WILL NEVER BE A RECORD REMOVAL FROM ANY TABLES.*****

///ADDITIONAL BACKGROUND INFO////////

The problem I am trying to solve is that when I update properties in a table, other distributed elements of the application are informed that they need to update their own state based on the new properties. I wanted to avoid passing the identifier of the new record in the remote calls and rely on a 'just look at the latest insert' approach - hence why I am trying to ensure that the row count equates to the ID of the latest record.

Comment: "*the number of records in the table will always equal the primary key value of the last insert*" - that's impossible. What do you do when you delete a row? And which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? Firebird?

Comment: The records should - there will never be a row edit or deletion. Just inserts. Not sure on DB yet - as long as it is supported by Hibernate.

Comment: What about failed inserts and a rollback? You can't guarantee that will never happen (and all "auto increment" values will not rollback the aquisition of a value). In a nutshell: you should never, ever rely on the PK value of a column to represent some state in the database. Can you explain what the real problem is that you are trying to solve? This sounds like a very bad plan.

Comment: Yep - can see why that would be a bad idea now - do you suggest I just pass the id in the remote calls? is there a good way to ask for the latest inserted record?

Comment: I don't know Hibernate but it should be able to return the generated key because native JDBC can. If you are e.g. using PostgreSQL, you can always get the last value of the sequence "manually".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply taken the advice  a_horse_with_no_name and generated ID's using Hibernates auto generation strategy - never requiring sequential input or assertions about the ID of an entity based on the number of rows in the table.